# Stripe Pricing Table - always use the same customer id

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a B2B software where subscriber company can have multiple subscriptions. We decided to move forward with pricing tables as we would like to utilize all benefits stripe suggests. When we render pricing table - we use "customer-email" property so on the checkout page email input is prepolulated and disabled which is good.

```
<stripe-pricing-table pricing-table-id="..."
                      customer-email="name@example.com"
                      client-reference-id="not_stripe_identifier"
                      publishable-key="...">
</stripe-pricing-table>
```

The problem is that if the same customer subscribe to different products and enter different payment methods - the system will create separate Customer in Stripe. We expected to see one customer and multiple subscriptions. Is there any chance to inject stripe customer id to stripe-pricing-table to prevent creation new customer every time? We still believe we could have one-to-one mapping between stripe customers and our internal software application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for the time being this is not supported, my only advice here is to contact https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true and ask for a feature request. This way you might get first access when this becomes available.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, you saved my time. Although it's a pity.

Comment: did you manage to contact them?

Comment: No, it is unclear how much time it will take, so we decided to move with some workarounds. Thank you,